# putImageData doesn't show image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I use the following function to update the contents of a canvas element, where frame_data is an array of `width*height*3`.

```
function updateCanvas(frame_data, width, height) {
    img = ctx.createImageData(width, height);

    for (i=0, j=0; j < frame_data.length; i++) {
        if ((i > 0) && (i%3==0)) {
            img.data[i] = 255;
        } else {
            img.data[i] = frame_data[j++];
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}`
```

It doesn't seem to work on Chrome 8, since I am getting this image as a result:

[image]

I've checked the `img.data` array produced by this function and the data are correct. So I assume that the problem is with the `putImageData` function. Has anyone else encountered the same problem? What could be wrong?

Comment: Paint an image with data coming from a pixel array of the form [r, g, b, r, g, b, ...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canvas imagedata array is not 3 entries per a pixel [r,g,b] but 4 [r,g,b,a] , so if the %3 is supposed to be setting the alpha value, it should really be %4.

At the moment, theres an exception for the first entry (0), then it sets the 4th entry (i=3) to 255 (correct), but next it sets the 7th entry (i=6) to 255, which means rather than [r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a] you have [r,g,b,a,r,g,a,b], and it gets worse over time.

Try

```
function updateCanvas(frame_data, width, height) {

    img = ctx.createImageData(width, height);

    for (i=0;j=0; j < frame_data.length; j=j+3) {
            img.data[i] = frame_data[j];
            img.data[i+1] = frame_data[j+1];
            img.data[i+2] = frame_data[j+2];
            img.data[i+3] = 255;
            i+=4;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}`
```

Comment: Oops! Can't believe I didn't realize that. Thanks a ton!